# How do I choose the right monitor for a multiple-monitor setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-display

I want to have a multiple-monitor setup. I plan on using a stand from a manufacturer such as Ergotron. How do I choose which monitors to purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I get into technical jargon, the short answer is your stand will snap or screw into almost every flat panel monitor or TV on the market.

Virtually all flat panel computer monitors and TVs use the [Flat Display Mounting Interface (FDMI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface), also known as VESA Mounting Interface Standard (MIS).  Most sizes of VESA mount have four screw-holes arranged in a square on the mount, with matching tapped holes on the device, the horizontal and vertical distance between the screw centers was originally 100 mm. A 75 mm × 75 mm layout was defined for smaller displays. Later, variants were added for screens as small as 4 inches diameter.

If you look at this LCD monitors [specs](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236052), you will see under the heading "Convenience" a sub-heading called VESA Compatible, with a value of 100 x 100mm - This is the standard.  There is no guarantee all the monitor specs will look like this, however its a fairy safe bet virtually all monitors adhere to this specification.